# Converting Fahrenheit to Celsius in php

Tags: php

Not sure why fahrenheit to celsius isn't working. Celsius to Fahren is working fine. Its possible I am missing something very simple, but I have no idea way. php noob here.

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['celsius'])) {
    $c = $_POST['celsius'];
    $f = ($c * 9/5) + 32;
    echo "<pre>$c Celsius is " .$f ." Fahrenheit</pre>";
}

if (isset($_POST['fahren'])) {
    $fah = $_POST['fahren'];
    $cen = ($fah - 32) / 1.8;
    echo "<pre>$fah Fahrenheit is " .$cen ." Celsius</pre>";
}

// (°F - 32) / 1.8 = °C


echo <<<_END

<pre>
<form method="post" action="10-unit-converter.php">

Celsius to Fahrenheit:
    <input type="text" name="celsius" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Fahrenheit" />

<br>

Fahrenheit to Celsius: 
    <input type="text" name"fahren" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Celsius" />



</form>
</pre>


_END

?>
```

Comment: Don't tell me it's the equal sign in `name"fahren"`

Comment: Thanks! Let me hide in shame...

Comment: happens to all of us. once spent six hours to figure out that `recieve` is different from `receive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name"fahren" size="7" />
```

Most likely the browser doesn't recognize the name of "fahren" input cause of a mistype and it's not passed to the php.

You are missing a `=`. `name="fahren"`.

Comment: eeek. I feel so ashamed of myself...

Answer (score 0):

You have missed = in html input:
**try this:**

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['celsius'])) {
    $c = $_POST['celsius'];
    $f = ($c * 9/5) + 32;
    echo "<pre>$c Celsius is " .$f ." Fahrenheit</pre>";
}

if (isset($_POST['fahren'])) {
    $fah = $_POST['fahren'];
    $cen = ($fah - 32) / 1.8;
    echo "<pre>$fah Fahrenheit is " .$cen ." Celsius</pre>";
}

// (°F - 32) / 1.8 = °C


echo <<<_END

<pre>
<form method="post" action="10-unit-converter.php">

Celsius to Fahrenheit:
    <input type="text" name="celsius" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Fahrenheit" />

<br>

Fahrenheit to Celsius: 
    <input type="text" name="fahren" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Celsius" />



</form>
</pre>
```